# @future sends to two methods

Tags: apex, future

My process I've been working on hits CPU time limit exception errors sometimes. So instead of using a batch process, I want to try to use @future methods to put some of the DML statements in the future asynchronously. I have two methods one creates a related record and one updates a record based on the related record.

Can I write something like this:

```
@future
 public static void futureFolk(Set<Id> filtered)
 {
  handlerclass.createRecord(filtered);
  handlerclass.updateRecord(filtered);
 }
}
```

Because one is based off the other I don't want to do two @future methods because one may not be finished by the time it starts. I also, want to try and seporate the concerns so I can test better so I don't think I should combine them into one giant method that inserts and updates records.

Is there a right way to do this?

If I don't use @future the records will get inserted and updated so I think that my base logic is right, just I need help with getting the order right for both to be done in the future.

Comment: You can use queueable classes. They are a betterment over future. The main advantage being that you can chain them so I think it will suit your case.

Comment: Whycan you not set all the data before insert? Update should not be necessary.

Comment: I'll check out the queueable class. @AdrianLarson I generate a bunch of schedule records by taking the difference between two days and dividing a currency field between them. I couldn't figure out how to mimic that logic and populate the correct field so I built the logic to create the record and then built another logic to look at that and update accordingly.